# Dynamic Table Rows with PHPWord

Tags: php, mysql, phpword

I am hoping someone can help me because I am attempting to do something that is beyond my limits, I don't even know if a function exists for this within PHP or MySQL so my search on google hasn't been very productive.

I am using PHPWord with my PHP/MySql Project, the intention is that I want to create a word document based on a template.

I have used this [guide](http://jeroen.is/phpword-templates-with-repeating-rows/) which is also on stack exchange.

However this approach requires that the number of rows and the values are hard coded, i.e. in his example he has used cloneRow('first_name', 3), which then clones the table to have 3 rows, and then goes on to manually define the tags, i.e.

```
$doc->setValue('first_name#1', 'Jeroen');
$doc->setValue('last_name#1', 'Moors');
$doc->setValue('first_name#2', 'John');
```

I am trying to make this dynamic, in my instance I am trying to make a timetable, and one of the child tables is exactly that, so the query I have looks up how many entries there are and then collects a count of them, this $count is then used to dynamically create the correct number of rows.  This is the count I am using:

```
$rs10 = CustomQuery("select count(*) as count FROM auditplanevents where AuditModuleFk='" . $result["AuditModulePk"]."'"); 
$data10 = db_fetch_array($rs10);
$Count = $data10["count"];
```

I then use this `$document->cloneRow('date', $Count);` to executive the clonerow function, which works great and my document now looks something like [this](http://prntscr.com/7b2ivz).

So, so far so good.

What I now want is for a way to then append each row value of the query into the document, so rather than manually setting the tag value i.e. `$doc->setValue('first_name#1', 'Jeroen');` I could use something like `$doc->setValue('first_name#1', '$name from row 1');`  I suspect this will involve a foreach query but not too sure.

I hope the above makes sense, but please feel free to ask me for anything else and become my personal hero.  Thanks

Update: Just for sake of clarity, what I would like is for the output to look something like this:

In my example are 5 results and therefore 5 rows created, I want to set values in following way:

```
${$date1} = date column from query 1st row
${$date2} = date column from query 2nd row
${$date3} = date column from query 3rd row
${$date4} = date column from query 4th row
${$date5} = date column from query 5th row
```

Comment: Could I use something like this http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/03/08/mysql-generating-row-number-for-each-row-using-variable/ to append to a temporary table (and truncate after use) ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to sort this out by inserting the records from the query into a temp table, with an AI ID, then using:

```
//update timetable with events from temp table
$rs14 = CustomQuery("select *  FROM tempauditplan where AuditModuleFk='" . $result["AuditModulePk"]."'"); 
while ($data14 = db_fetch_array($rs14))
    {
        $document->setValue('date#'.$data14["rowid"], date('d/m/y', strtotime($data14["date"])));
        $document->setValue('time#'.$data14["rowid"], date('H:i', strtotime($data14["time"])));
        $document->setValue('auditor#'.$data14["rowid"], $data14["auditor"]);
        $document->setValue('area#'.$data14["rowid"], $data14["area"]);
        $document->setValue('notes#'.$data14["rowid"], $data14["notes"]);
        $document->setValue('contact#'.$data14["rowid"], $data14["contact"]);
    }
```

The trick is to also have a function that truncates the table after use so can be used over again

Might not be the most efficient way, but it works!